# In vis-network, how is horizontal order determined in hierarchical layout?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

In [this example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/layout/hierarchicalLayoutUserdefined.html), `"level"` is used to control the vertical position a node is put at (assuming `hierarchical.direction` is `up-down`).

[image]

However, I didn't find how to set the **horizontal order for nodes on the same hierarchy**. For example, if I want to put `node 6` in front of `node 1`, is there a way to do it?

My understanding is that the horizontal order is purely determined by **node insertion order**, is it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/926, the order is non-deterministic. Quote:

> Q: I didn't find how to set the **horizontal order for nodes on the same hierarchy**. For example, if I want to put `node 6` in front of `node 1`, is there a way to do it?
>
> A: As far as the public API goes: No, the order is not guaranteed in any way, do not rely on it, it may change with any new release or between browsers.
>
> Q: My understanding is that the horizontal order is purely determined by **node insertion order**, is it correct?
>
> A: As far as the CURRENT implementation and decent browsers go: Yes.

Comment: I understand it's not supported with public API. Is there any custom way to change data nodes manipulated by expecting its position outside and set it back, ideally not resetting all nodes, but children nodes only?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that if you're generating nodes and edges dynamically via user interactions and want to ensure the nodes and edges are ordered correctly, here's the way to do it:

After the user interaction, clear the nodes and edges first via the [`clear`](https://visjs.github.io/vis-data/data/dataset.html#Clear) method, then use [`add`](https://visjs.github.io/vis-data/data/dataset.html#Add) to add the newest nodes and edges by the desired insertion order.